# Laravel: Route not found error

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4

I have a newbie question in laravel. I'm trying to query a DB. I have already modified the config to include the necessary credentials for my DB. Now, when i try to query my DB like this:

```
 <?php
 /*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Application Routes
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
 | It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
 | and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
 |
 */
 Route::get('/', function()
 {
   $topPages = DB::table('webmasters') -> get();
   return $topPages;
 });
```

I get: Fatal error:

> Class 'Route' not found in /.../.../.../dashboard/app/routes.php on
>   line 13.

I have followed laracast video for accessing a database to the letter, can someone pls tell me what i'm missing or doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you namespaced your app? Try `\Route::get()`

Comment: Like i mentioned, i'm really green here. What does namespacing mean in this context? And where do i put this \Route::get()

Comment: Change your code from `Route::get(` to `\Route::get(`

Comment: Tried that. Problem persists.

Comment: Could you show the top of your `routesDB.php` file, and the 3rd line ?

Comment: There is nothing else at the top of routesDB, just what i posted above.php and the 3rd line is the Route::get(...)line.

Comment: Why don't you declare the route in your `app/routes.php` file ?

Comment: I have declared the route in the app/routes.php file and edited the question to this effect(see above). The problem still persists.

Comment: Are you using laravel's standard file structure?

Comment: Yes i am using the standard structure.

Comment: When you visit the page, are you putting a trailing / on the end? If so, remove it and see if it works.

Comment: No i'm not putting a trailing forward slash.

Comment: Have you updated composer? Or have you successfully installed laravel? dependency error there.

Answer (score 3):

maybe the route cache issue run command

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solutions:

1. Update the app by composer (`composer update`)
2. Check for file permission